# I define a constant and it doesn't show up in an for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So I am learning to program and im a beginner. I have an array with several strings "name;age;m/f" inside and i have to convert each one to capitalise the first letter in name, add " years" to age, and change m/f to male or female. I tried to do this in a loop like this

```
const people = ["mark;16;m" , "carl;18;m" , "emma;20;f"]
for(let z = 0 ; z < people.length ; z++){
            people[z] = (people[z].split(";"));
            people[z[0]] = people[z[0]].toUpperCase(0);
            people[z[1]] = people[z[1]] + " years";
            if(people[z[2]] === "m") osoby[z[2]] = "male"               
            else people[z[2]] = "female";
        }
```

When i run the code an error pops up in the console "Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined", how can i fix this?

Comment: `people[z]` becomes an array after split() ...the new sub array elements are accessed by `people[z][n]`, ...not by using `z[n]`. What are expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
people[z[0]] = people[z[0]].toUpperCase(0);
```

you should use

```
people[z][0] = people[z][0].toUpperCase(0);
```

That's how nested array access works. `z[0]` just evaluates to undefined because z is a number.

Answer (score -1):

It should work if you remove the z. It should be people[0] not people [z[0]].

Comment: `people[z] = (people[z].split(";"));` in this line i change the array into several arrays [name , age , m/f] so that won't work because its a constant

Comment: There would be no point in using a loop if you only ever target `people[0]`. This does not solve OP's issue